# Cannot read a txt file

Tags: java, file-io

```
import java.io.*;
public class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;
    public Point(double x_coord, double y_coord) {
        x = x_coord;
        y = y_coord;
    }
}
public class PointArray {
    private Point points[];
    public PointArray(FileInputStream fileIn) throws IOException {
        try {
            BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIn));
            int numberOfPoints = Integer.parseInt(inputStream.readLine())...points = new Point[numberOfPoints];
            int i = 0;
            String line;
            while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.print(line);
                double x = Double.parseDouble(line.split(" ")[0]);
                double y = Double.parseDouble(line.split(" ")[1]);
                points[i] = new Point(x, y);
                i++;
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
public String toString() {
    String format = "{";
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        if (i < points.length - 1) format = format + points[i] + ", ";
        else format = format + points[i];
    }
    format = format + "}";
    return format;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileInputStream five = new FileInputStream(new File("fivePoints.txt"));
    PointArray fivePoints = new PointArray(five);
    System.out.println(fivePoints.toString());
}
```

The txt file fivePoints is as shown below:

```
5 
2 7 
3 5 
11 17 
23 19 
150 1
```

The first number in the first line means the number of points in the text file.
There is an error when I read the file. The output I want to get is {(2.0, 7.0), (3.0, 5.0), (11.0,17.0), (23.0, 19.0), (150.0, 1.0)}. How can I fix it?

Comment: Well, the `toString` method should be declared within the `PointArray` method

Comment: I do but it doesn't work.

Comment: No, in you example code, `toString` is declared out side of the `PointArray` method, so it won't

Comment: @Chriseagles looking at your profile, you have accepted no answer for all the questions you have asked so far. Even though it is not mandatory to accept an answer for a question, it is helpful because A) it helps others with same issue find the answer that resolved the question B) marking an answer as accepted motivates people to answer your question in the future. Don't forget you also get points for accepting an answer. To accept an answer, you click the tick icon for whichever answer that resolved your issue. More on how to accept an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2):

Add a `toString` method to your `Point` which formats the `Point` as `x, y`

```
public class Point {
    //...        
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + ", " + y;
    }
}
```

Move your `toString` method so it's defined in `PointArray`, you might also consider making use of `StringJoiner` to make your life simpler

```
public class PointArray {
    //...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ", "{", "}");
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            sj.add("(" + points[i].toString() + ")");
        }
        return sj.toString();
    }
}
```